# Integer appears with quoted with PDO's execute in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using a global function to handle my MySQL requirements in PHP. Here is the code:

```
function DB_EXECUTE($query, array $array_par, $haveresult = 1){
global $db;
try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($array_par);
}catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "ERROR: " . $query . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
$rowF = null;
if ($haveresult > 0){
$rowF = $stmt->fetchAll();
}  
return $rowF;
}
```

I call the function like this:

```
$temp_query = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT :one, :two";
$temp_array = array(":one" => intval($limit_from), ":two" => intval($limit_to));
$results =  DB_EXECUTE($temp_query, $temp_array, 1);
//Do something with the $results
```

But I face a problem:

```
ERROR: SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT :one, :two
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0', '5'' at line 1
```

I handle a lot of queries with this function so I don't want to change the way I call it. Instead I want to change the function itself to support Integer type of data.

Comment: Try to use `bindParam` in your function.

Comment: @Daan Count of $array_par is unknown! How can I use bindParam with that?

Comment: Change your code in DB_EXECUTE() 'try' block as follows.  

    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':one', $array_par[":one"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':two', $array_par[":two"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

Comment: @TismonVarghese The count of parameters are unknown! It could be 1 parameter in a query to 10 parameters or even some queries without any parameter!